# MySQL - query to return CSV in a field?

Tags: mysql

Assume I have the following tables:

```
TABLE: foo
- foo_id (PK)

TABLE: tag
- tag_id (PK)
- name

TABLE: foo_tag
- foo_tag_id (PK)
- foo_id (FK)
- tag_id (FK)
```

How do I query this so that I get a result like this:

```
==========================
| foo_id | tags          |
==========================
| 1      | foo, bar      |
| 2      | foo           |
| 3      | bar           |
--------------------------
```

Basically, I need all of `foo`'s tags in one column, comma separated. Possible in MySQL?

Comment: I think you could use GROUP_CONCAT for that:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Can you show me a sample query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select f.foo_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tags
from foo f, tag t, foo_tag as ft
where f.foo_id = ft.foo_id and ft.tag_id = t.tag_id
group by f.foo_id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: This uses comma as the delimiter? Or is there no delimiter?

Comment: Comma is used as a default seperator. @StackOverflowNewbie

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     f.foo_id, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(t.name separator ', ') as tags
FROM 
     foo f, 
     tag t, 
     foo_tag as fOt
WHERE f.foo_id = fOt.foo_id 
AND fOt.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY f.foo_id
```

Here i used a **comma and space** as a separator.